# how to update a matplotlib heatmap plot without creating a new window

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, matplotlib, heatmap

I have matrix class that inherits from list. This class can display itself as a matplotlib heatmap representation of the matrix.

I'm trying to have the class written such that when I change values in the matrix, I can call the matrix's method `plot()` and it'll update the plot to reflect the matrix changes in the heatmap.

However, every time I run the method `plot()`, it creates a new heatmap in a new window instead of updating the existing plot. How could I get it simply to *update* the existing plot?

In the code below, there are three main parts: the main function shows how an instance of the matrix class is created, plotted and updated; the matrix class is basically a list object, with some minor functionality (including plotting) bolted on; the function `plotList()` is the function the matrix class calls in order to generate the plot object initially.

```
import time
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
import numpy as np

def main():

    print("plot 2 x 2 matrix and display it changing in a loop")
    matrix = Matrix(
        numberOfColumns = 2,
        numberOfRows    = 2,
        randomise       = True
    )
    # Plot the matrix.
    matrix.plot()
    # Change the matrix, redrawing it after each change.
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for column in range(len(matrix[row])):
            input("Press Enter to continue.")
            matrix[row][column] = 10
            matrix.plot()
    input("Press Enter to terminate.")
    matrix.closePlot()

class Matrix(list):

    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        numberOfColumns          = 3,
        numberOfRows             = 3,
        element                  = 0.0,
        randomise                = False,
        randomiseLimitLower      = -0.2,
        randomiseLimitUpper      = 0.2
        ):
        # list initialisation
        super().__init__(self, *args)   
        self.numberOfColumns     = numberOfColumns
        self.numberOfRows        = numberOfRows
        self.element             = element
        self.randomise           = randomise
        self.randomiseLimitLower = randomiseLimitLower
        self.randomiseLimitUpper = randomiseLimitUpper
        # fill with default element
        for column in range(self.numberOfColumns):
            self.append([element] * self.numberOfRows)
        # fill with pseudorandom elements
        if self.randomise:
            random.seed()
            for row in range(self.numberOfRows):
                for column in range(self.numberOfColumns):
                    self[row][column] = random.uniform(
                        self.randomiseLimitUpper,
                        self.randomiseLimitLower
                    )
        # plot
        self._plot               = plotList(
                                       list  = self,
                                       mode  = "return"
                                   )
        # for display or redraw plot behaviour
        self._plotShown          = False

    def plot(self):
        # display or redraw plot
        self._plot.draw()
        if self._plotShown:
            #self._plot            = plotList(
            #                            list  = self,
            #                            mode  = "return"
            #                        )
            array = np.array(self)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            heatmap = ax.pcolor(array, cmap = plt.cm.Blues)
            self._plot.draw()
        else:
            self._plot.show()
            self._plotShown = True

    def closePlot(self):
        self._plot.close()

def plotList(
    list  = list,
    mode  = "plot" # plot/return
    ):
    # convert list to NumPy array
    array = np.array(list)
    # create axis labels
    labelsColumn = []
    labelsRow = []
    for rowNumber in range(0, len(list)):
        labelsRow.append(rowNumber + 1)
        for columnNumber in range(0, len(list[rowNumber])):
            labelsColumn.append(columnNumber)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    heatmap = ax.pcolor(array, cmap = plt.cm.Blues)
    # display plot or return plot object
    if mode == "plot":
        plt.show()
    elif mode == "return":
        return(plt)
    else:
        Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm using Python 3 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `plot(self)` creates a new figure in the line `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. To use an existing figure you can give your [figure](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) a number or name when it's first created in `plotList()`:

```
fig = plt.figure('matrix figure')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

then use

```
plt.figure('matrix figure') 
ax = gca() # gets current axes
```

to make that the active figure and [axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gca). Alternately, you might want to the figure and axis created in `plotList` and pass them to `plot`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on that. I did as you suggested, returning the figure and axes objects from the plot creation function.

Comment: @d3pd do you have the final working code?